# How to bind to property on viewmodel that is not the current binding context

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, binding

I have a label:

```
<Label BindingContext="{Binding BModel}"
       Text="{Binding BoundDataItem.CurrentValue.Value}"
       IsVisible="{Binding IsEditButtonShown}"/>
```

Without the Binding context the IsVisible property works just like it should, but now I need to have the binding context for a specific piece of data but I still need IsVisible property to work. The IsEditButtonShown is a property on my view model.

I have tried:

```
IsVisible="{Binding IsEditButtonShown, Source={x:Reference CurrentPagename}}
```

Did nothing, and

```
IsVisible="{Binding IsEditButtonShown, Source={x:Reference CurrentViewModel}}
```

Gave an error about not being able to find the ViewModel (this was after adding it to page at the top with xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace..."

I have also tried going the other way where I use the Source=x:Reference with the BModel but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently I'm an idiot. it seems I didn't really need the BindingContext for that item after all. Now the Label looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding BModel.BoundDataItem.CurrentValue.Value}"
       IsVisible="{Binding IsEditButtonShown}"/>
```

and it appears to work like it's supposed to.

Funny how things come to you when you start explaining them to others.